# In Linux (CentOS) how can I find large folders?

Tags: linux, command-line, centos

How can search for large folders but find them down to the smallest level?

Meaning if `/home/user/wp-content/updraft/2020/June/` has 200 zip files that are 50mb each I don't want to get back that the largest folder is `/home/` I want to see the full string down to the `/June/`

I'm good with making it only show folders that are larger than 1GB or something.

Comment: “I'm good with making it only show folders that are larger than 1GB or something.” Can you post your attempts at doing this?  What have you done so far to achieve this goal? This site is not a free scripting service. The community here helps those who help themselves. So if you have attempted to do something to achieve this goal, please post your code/script/formula and the community can attempt to help you. As it stands this question reads as a free scripting request and will most likely be closed as a result.

Comment: From the linked duplicates try `ncdu` first. It's interactive and lets you navigate to deeper directories easily, back and forth (use arrows).